# How to trigger org-mobile-push from bash?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, org-mode

On Ubuntu 14.04 I frequently use M-x org-mobile-push on Emacs GUI. Now I'm writting a script (bash) and I was wondering how could I trigger the extended-command org-mobile-push from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Emacs in batch mode easily.  You'll apparently need to have it load your `.emacs` file separately in order for it to suck in your `org-mode` preferences before evaluating code from the command line.

```
emacs --batch --load ~/.emacs \
      --eval "(progn (require 'org-mobile) (org-mobile-push))"
```